# How to make breadcrumb on Angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, breadcrumbs

I try to make breadcrumb with Angular 6. Texts work but links doesn't work correctly.

I want to do this.

**Home > Dashboard > Statistical** ( It Works.)

Home -> **xxx.com** (It works.)

Dashborad -> **xxx.com/dashboard** (It works.)

Statistical -> **xxx.com/statistical** (It doesn't work.)

So, if it is subcomponent links don't work.

It needs to be **xxx.com/dashboard/statistical** (Correct)

How can i do this ?

**breadcrumb.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumb',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumb.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumb.component.scss']
})
export class BreadcrumbComponent implements OnInit {
  route: string;
  breadcrumbList: Array<any>;
  routeLinks: number;
  count: number;

  constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (location.path() !== '') {
        this.route = location.path();
        this.breadcrumbList = this.route.split('/');
        this.count = this.breadcrumbList.length;
      } else {
        this.route = 'Home';
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**breadcrumb.component.html**

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <ng-container *ngIf="count == null">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="material-icons">home</i></li>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="count != null">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]=""><i class="material-icons">home</i></a></li>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let breadLink of breadcrumbList">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="breadcrumbList[2]">{{breadLink}}</a></li>
    </ng-container>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: I checked no of articles, but I am unable to identify the best and suitable dynamic breadcrumb for the angular2 project.

Finally, I have written a pretty easy angular npm module for the dynamic breadcrumb. Please refer the below URL and integrate into your application.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-breadcrumb

Comment: This might help you. [angular-breadcrumb-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-breadcrumb-demo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reconstruct every url link with previous url prefixed -

```
    this.breadcrumbList = this.route.split('/');
    this.breadcrumbLinksList  = [this.breadcrumbList[0]];

    for(let i=1; i<=this.breadcrumbList.length; i++){
      const link = this.breadcrumbLinksList[i-1] +'/'+ this.breadcrumbList[i]
      this.breadcrumbLinksList.push(link)
    }
```

Use in html as -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let breadcrumbLabel of breadcrumbList; let i=index">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <a [routerLink]="breadcrumbLinksList[i]">{{breadcrumbLabel}}</a>
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

For more elaborate usage of breadcrumbs, I think xng-breadcrumb (https://github.com/udayvunnam/xng-breadcrumb) covers all your use cases along with few other useful features. Any breadcrumb solution has to handle

- declarative approach of defining breadcrumbs in routing Dynamic
- asynchronous way to update any route by a different label way to skip
- specific routes from displaying in breadcrumbs

Feel free to check usage of breadcrumbs in a production ready Angular App https://xng-breadcrumb.netlify.com